# Permissions on REST resources

Tags: rest, permissions

I'm writing a set of rest services, and in some of the resources, i'm dealing with the following situation. For example:

with a resource:

/articles

Users can create articles, Users can't delete any article. Users can get a list of all the articles that they have created (GET /articles), but cannot see the articles of other users. There will be a special set of "admin" users, that will have plenty of rights to see, or delete any of the articles.

I see two approaches to this:

- Having only one endpoint as with the example, and deal with permissions inside the service's code for POST, GET and DELETE
- Having a different endpoint /admin/articles, with a separated implementations, and deal with permissions just after authentication and before the service code.

Which do you think it's better/cleaner/RESTfullish?

Comment: I can't speak on the "restfulness", but since you're working with the same resources with at least partially the same operations and only different permissions, I'd find it a bit odd to separate the endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two users can create articles with the same identifier, then it's 'cleaner' and easier to represent them at a deeper level like a filesystem.

> /{username}/articles

If they are all creating articles in the same user space, then per resource authorization is more adequate.

Comment: Makes sense for GET, but Let's say that when using that structure `/{username}/articles` a normal user will add an article by POST on that resource. What if an admin user has to be able to write an article in a particular user namespace, (impersonating another user). Would it be better to post this on the user space, o in a separate /admin/articles service?

Comment: You can see it as impersonation, but /{username} is nothing more than a location to which the admin user has write permissions. The identity of the user performing the action is handled through other means like authentication headers. If an admin needs to write their own articles, then they can behave like regular users.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the 1st approach - having the same endpoint for the following reasons:

1. Cleaner and easier to understand.
2. Easier maintenance - suppose you will have more roles in the future. This will force to create more endpoints for each role you add.
3. Loose coupling. By using this approach you decouple your application's authorization concerns from the API itself.
4. You have to check authorization in the code itself anyway, to check that a client calls an unauthorized resource, so you don't really save anything by using the 2nd approach.